# Is it possible to clone objects with a name diferent in blender at a runtime?

Tags: python, game-engine

I want to generate in Blender Game Engine at a runtime, multiples objects with a diferents names that I can select them individuals. Is it possible? If yes, how can  I make it?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to generate ... multiples objects with a diferents names ... 
>   Is it possible?

No, it is not.

When you create an object then you already know the object. You do not need to search for it.